# Does wide character input/output in C always read from / write to the correct (system default) encoding?

Tags: c, linux, posix, wchar-t

I'm primarily interested in the Unix-like systems (e.g., portable POSIX) as it seems like Windows does strange things for wide characters.

Do the read and write wide character functions (like `getwchar()` and `putwchar()`) always "do the right thing", for example read from utf-8 and write to utf-8 when that is the set locale, or do I have to manually call `wcrtomb()` and print the string using e.g. `fputs()`? On my system (openSUSE 12.3) where `$LANG` is set to `en_GB.UTF-8` they do seem to do the right thing (inspecting the output I see what looks like UTF-8 even though strings were stored using wchar_t and written using the wide character functions).

However I am unsure if this is guaranteed. For example [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) states that:

> [wide characters] should not be used for output, since spurious zero
>   bytes and other low-ASCII characters with common meanings (such as '/'
>   and '\n') will likely be sprinkled throughout the data.

Which seems to indicate that outputting wide characters (presumably using the wide character output functions) can wreak havoc.

Since the C standard does not seem to mention coding at all I really have no idea who/when/how coding is applied when using wchar_t. So my question is basically if reading, writing and using wide characters exclusively is a proper thing to do when my application has no need to know about the encoding used. I only need string lengths and console widths (`wcswidth()`), so to me using wchar_t everywhere when dealing with text seems ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant text governing the behavior of the wide character stdio functions and their relationship to locale is from POSIX XSH 2.5.2 Stream Orientation and Encoding Rules:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_02

Basically, the wide character stdio functions always write in the encoding that's in effect (per the `LC_CTYPE` locale category) at the time the `FILE` stream becomes wide-oriented; this means the first time a wide stdio function is called on it, or `fwide` is used to set the orientation to wide. So as long as a proper `LC_CTYPE` locale is in effect matching the desired "system" encoding (e.g. UTF-8) when you start working with the stream, everything should be fine.

However, one important consideration you should not overlook is that you **must not** mix byte and wide oriented operations on the same `FILE` stream. Failure to observe this rule is not a reportable error; it simply results in *undefined behavior*. As a good deal of library code assumes `stderr` is byte oriented (and some even makes the same assumption about `stdout`), I would strongly discourage **ever** using wide-oriented functions on the standard streams. If you do, you need to be very careful about which library functions you use.

Really, I can't think of any reason at all to use wide-oriented functions. `fprintf` is perfectly capable of sending wide-character strings to byte-oriented `FILE` streams using the `%ls` specifier.

Comment: I assume using putwchar(wc) yields better performance than having to use printf("%lc", wc), but for my current use that performance difference probably isn't important. But just to be clear, setting stdout to wide orientation will only be problematic if library functions actually write to stdout, correct?

Comment: @Quantumboredom: Yes. `stdout` begins with no orientation, but once you write using a wide character function, it's set to wide and you  mustn't use byte functions on it any more (`stderr` remains unaffected). I can't think of any standard library functions that will use `stdout`, but external libraries might.

Comment: @teppic: Ok, in my application anything else writing to stdout would be a bug anyway, and I measured performance dropping to half when using printf("%lc", wc) versus putwchar(wc) so I think I'll stick with wide output on stdout. Thanks by the way for linking to the relevant standard in your answer :-)

Comment: @Quantumboredom - that was R.. :) I updated my answer with your question for completion.

Comment: @teppic: Ah, I didn't notice. Thanks to you both :-)

Answer (score 10):

So long as the locale is set correctly, there shouldn't be any issues processing UTF-8 files on a system using UTF-8, using the wide character functions. They'll be able to interpret things correctly, i.e. they'll treat a character as 1-4 bytes as necessary (in both input and output). You can test it out by something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_GB.UTF-8");
    // setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); // to use environment variable instead
    wchar_t *txt = L"£Δᗩ";

    wprintf(L"The string %ls has %d characters\n", txt, wcslen(txt));
}

$ gcc -o loc loc.c && ./loc
The string £Δᗩ has 3 characters
```

If you use the standard functions (in particular character functions) on multibyte strings carelessly, things will start to break, e.g. the equivalent:

```
char *txt = "£Δᗩ";
printf("The string %s has %zu characters\n", txt, strlen(txt));

$ gcc -o nloc nloc.c && ./nloc
The string £Δᗩ has 7 characters
```

The string still prints correctly here because it's essentially just a stream of bytes, and as the system is expecting UTF-8 sequences, they're translated perfectly. Of course `strlen` is reporting the number of bytes in the string, 7 (plus the `\0`), with no understanding that a character and a byte aren't equivalent.

In this respect, because of the compatibility between ASCII and UTF-8, you can often get away with treating UTF-8 files as simply multibyte C strings, as long as you're careful.

There's a degree of flexibility as well. It's possible to convert a standard C string (as a multibyte string) to a wide character string easily:

```
char *stdtxt = "ASCII and UTF-8 €£¢";
wchar_t buf[100]; 
mbstowcs(buf, stdtxt, 20);

wprintf(L"%ls has %zu wide characters\n", buf, wcslen(buf));

Output:
ASCII and UTF-8 €£¢ has 19 wide characters
```

Once you've used a wide character function on a stream, it's set to wide orientation. If you later want to use standard byte i/o functions, you'll need to re-open the stream first. This is probably why the recommendation is not to use it on `stdout`. However, if you only use wide character functions on `stdin` and `stdout` (including any code that you link to), you will not have any problems.

Comment: 'Break' is not quite right.  The description should be 'The string occupies 7 bytes', which is accurate.  That it contains only 3 characters is also correct.  This is a difference in part between multi-byte strings (`mbs*` functions) and wide-character strings (`wcs*` functions).  However, that's nitpicking; your core answer is fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I was just editing to address what I said as you wrote that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - heh, that's ok. I've filled it out a bit.

Comment: @teppic: Thanks for the examples, your answer was also very good.

Comment: Use `strnlen`, not `strlen`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `fputs` with anything else than ASCII.

If you want to write down lets say UTF8,  then use a function who return the real size used by the utf8 string and use fwrite to write the good number of bytes, without worrying of vicious '`\0`' inside the string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `fputs()` outputs a byte string up to the first zero byte. UTF-8 contains only one character value with a zero byte, and that's U+0000 (encoded as `'\0'` in UTF-8). So `fputs()` won't mishandle a null-terminated UTF-8 string. Indeed, one of the merits of UTF-8 is that a naîve program that is unaware of UTF-8 can often handle the strings correctly even so. (Not always — there are plenty of ways to cause trouble; but often...) Also, `fputs()` is fine for single-byte codesets such as ISO 8859-1 or 8859-15 (8859-2, ...). Limiting it to ASCII is unjustifiably stringent.

Comment: Hi,
He is not compiling as full utf8. He's using utf8 string in ascii compiled source.

Comment: And fputs will fail because utf8 are not one byte encoded strings.

Comment: Better than that he should use wchar and fputws(const wchar_t *restrict, FILE *restrict);

Comment: `fputs()` will not fail just because UTF8 is a multi-byte code set. Indeed, one of the goals of the design of UTF8 was to let naïve programs that are unaware of UTF8 still process it successfully. Your assertion that `fputs()` is only good for ASCII is blatantly wrong, even taking a charitable interpretation that you mean 'a single-byte code set based on ASCII, such as 8859-1'. Note that UTF8 is a multi-byte code set (or character encoding), not one that uses wide characters; you would not handle UTF8 with wide-character functions. UTF16 and UTF32 are wide-character representations of Unicode.

Comment: Now, if you are trying to argue that you cannot use `fputs()` to output a wide-character string, then I'd agree with you, but that isn't what your answer says at all. Your answer largely avoids answering the actual question, in fact.

Comment: My answer says what it says: writing will fail. Which mean the behavior will not be what attended. Why: because of encoding.
Plus I'm not the one arguing there. You are. \0 is zero. Lots of multibytes ancoded characters will have single 0 in a byte which mean no more writting with fputs.