# cout<< "привет"; or wcout<< L"привет";

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, console-application

Why

```
cout<< "привет";
```

works well while

```
wcout<< L"привет";
```

does not? (in Qt Creator for linux)

Comment: Presumably, because whatever receives those characters as output "doesn't understand wide characters". If you describe "Doesn't work" a little more, it may help.

Comment: it prints ???? instead in terminal window. However how "привет" can be  unicode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

GCC and Clang defaults to treat the source file as UTF-8. Your Linux terminal is most probably configured to UTF-8 as well. So with `cout<< "привет"` there is a UTF-8 string which is printed in a UTF-8 terminal, all is well.

`wcout<< L"привет"` depends on a proper [Locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) configuration in order to convert the wide characters into the terminal's character encoding. The Locale needs to be initialized in order for the conversion to work (the [default "classic" aka "C" locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global) doesn't know how to convert the wide characters). Use `std::locale::global (std::locale (""))` for the Locale to match the environment configuration or `std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"))` to use a specific Locale ([similar to this C example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455884/257568)).

Here's the full source of the working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));
  wcout << L"привет\n";
}
```

With `g++ test.cc && ./a.out` this prints "привет" (on Debian Jessie).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457239/257568) about dangers of using wide characters with standard output.

Comment: thanks.  yet it's surprising that "привет" is not std literal it should be `char[]`.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: "привет" is char[] in UTF-8 by default, L"привет", however, is wchar[] in UTF-16, UTF-32 or UCS-2.

Comment: Code above compiled in Windows gnu g++, outputs this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' 
 what(): locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid`.

Comment: @Salvador So? The question was about Linux. If your GCC port doesn't have the "en_US.UTF-8" locale then catch the exception and use `std::locale::global (std::locale (""))` or install the locale.